# Comparing an object to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a JavaScript object that I'm trying to compare to an array of objects:

```
var builtVehicle = {pattern: "../images/fire1192015.png", 
vehicle: "../images/van1192015.png", 
wheel: "../images/wheels3.png"};

var createdVehicles = [
{pattern:"../images/checkerboard1192015.png",       
vehicle:"../images/car1192015.png", wheel:"../images/wheels1.png"}, 
{pattern:"../images/fire1192015.png", vehicle:"../images/truck1192015.png",     
wheel:"../images/wheels4.png"},]
```

I am attempting to loop through both the JavaScript object and the createdVehicles array of objects looking for an exact match.  If there is not an exact match, I want to add the builtVehicle object to the createdVehicles array. My thought is to compare each key/value pair of the objects in the array with the builtVehicle object, but I was having some problems pulling out the key/value pairs within the array.  My loops look like this:

```
for(var key in builtVehicle) {
    console.log('builtVehicle key: ' + key + '\n' + 'builtVehicle value: ' +     
builtVehicle[key]);
}


for(var b=0; b < createdVehicles.length; b++){
    alert(createdVehicles[b]);
}
```

Is this the best approach to take?  I was also looking into 2D arrays to accomplish this, but any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no `.obj` property for your "createdVehicles" array; each indexed element of the array is an object.

Comment: Uh, nest your loops?

Comment: Right, I didn't mean to include the .obj property in the "createdVehicles" for loop.  Bergi, I was planning on nesting the second loop in the first one, just wasn't sure what sort of code would pull the key value pairs out of the array.

Comment: `createdVehicles[b].vehicle`, `createdVehicles[b].pattern`, etc, or `createdVehicles[b][key]` if you're looping with `for ... in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say this would be the best approach. Ultimately, I would alter the data structure like @Brodie says. Otherwise you can do something like this...

```
var builtVehicle = {
  pattern: "../images/fire1192015.png", 
  vehicle: "../images/van1192015.png", 
  wheel: "../images/wheels3.png"
};

var createdVehicles = [
{
  pattern:"../images/checkerboard1192015.png",       
  vehicle:"../images/car1192015.png", 
  wheel:"../images/wheels1.png"
}, 
{
  pattern:"../images/fire1192015.png", 
  vehicle:"../images/truck1192015.png",     
   wheel:"../images/wheels4.png"
}
];


var matchVehicle = function (vehicle, stack) {

  var i=0;

  for (i; i < stack.length; i+=1) {

      // if you have an id, thats even better because you don't have to test all of this, otherwise what makes it unique? a combo of everything?
      if ((vehicle.pattern === stack[i].pattern) && (vehicle.vehicle === stack[i].vehicle) && (vehicle.wheel === stack[i].wheel)) {
          return stack[i]; // returns the matching vehicle.
      }
  }
  // Will push the vehicle if it didn't match
  stack.push(vehicle);

};

console.log(matchVehicle(builtVehicle, createdVehicles));
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I was able to get the check working with your approach!

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the data strucutre, something like this might be better, depending on what you're going to do the createdVehicles and if it needs to be an array.

```
// indexed by id of the vehicle, this could be a model number or something instead, but just need some identifying key for comparison.
// structure of item: { identifyingKey : vehicleObject }
createdVehicles = {
  1 : { ... },
  2 : { ... }
 }

if (!createVehicles.hasOwnProperty(builtVehicle.id)) {
  createdVehicles[builtVehicle.id] = builtVehicle;
}
```

if you're stuck with your contstraints it's probably best to take the straight forward approach and iterate over the array. The comment was right in that the old way assumed that the vehicle was the same based off one key. Here was create a function to do a ddper object comparison, then use it to check for matches in the vehicle array. if there is a match we break out, if not then match stays false and we know to add it to the array upon finish of the loop. This is a little heavy and long winded, but with no libraries this should work. Sorry for syntax errors and stuff, at work so tried to do this quickly.

```
//if you have access to underscore you can use _.size(obj) instead
// otherwise having access ot the size of the object helps, idk how people
// feel about touching the object protoype itself, but this is quick and dirty
Object.prototype.size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};

var match = false;

var isVehicle = function(builtVehicle, testVehicle) {
  if (builtVehicle.size() !== testVehicle.size()) {
     return false;
  }

  for (key in builtVehicle) {
    if (!testVehicle.hasOwnProperty[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

for (var i = 0, len = createdVehicles.length; i < len; i++) {
  var testVehicle = createdVehicles[i],
      match = isVehicle(builtVehicle, testVehicle);

   //if there was a match break out
   if (match) {
     break;
   }
}

if (!match) {
  createdVehicles.push(builtVehicle);
}
```

since people have mentioned underscore, if you had access to that you could do something like:

```
for (var i = 0, len = createdVehicles.length; i < len; i++) {
  var testVehicle = createdVehicles[i],
      match = _.isEqual(builtVehicle, testVehicle);

   //if there was a match break out
   if (match) {
     break;
   }
}

if (!match) {
  createdVehicles.push(builtVehicle);
}
```

Comment: This is considering that the vehicle property is a unique id